# How can I answer a POST request with a static file in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra

In Sinatra, if you have a "GET /images/photo1.jpg" request... you can save a lot of time by making a "public" directory. Any route not found is assumed to be inside your "public" directory.

However this seems to work just for GET requests. Is there a way to do something similar for POST requests?

Either:

- Turning on some static method?
- Maybe forging an inner request?
- Duplicating functionality?

Any ideas? Is this even a bug?

PS: I know it's not RESTful to ask for files in a POST request, unfortunately Facebook works that way.

Comment: Facebook is far from RESTful, too bad they think their API is one.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like something you should attack with rack middleware.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough Rack to do it. I cannot vendor either.

What I did to fix my situation (not to answer this...) was switching to iframe. That way, my files are called by a GET.

Answer (score 0):

The [send_file](http://www.sinatrarb.com/api/classes/Sinatra/Helpers.html#M000019) helper is what you want.

```
send_file "/your/file.txt", {:filename=>"foobar.dat"}
```